# fade from different colours

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the background colour to change every 750 ms to a different colour (needs to be bright colours) but fade so its not just flicking between colours. So basically just need some javascript to change the background colour and fade bewteen them every 750 ms. Also, this can be done in jQuery if you prefer.

Comment: Have you considered just using CSS animations for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, try jQueryUI's animate, something like:

```
setInterval(changeColor, 750);
colors = ['red','blue','yellow'];
i = 0;   

function changeColor(){
    $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: colors[i] }, 750);
    i++;
    i = i == colors.length?0:i;
}
```

Of course, dont forget to include the library: http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

Edit: Use this for good, don't give your users a headache!

Comment: Haha, I wasn't planning on doing that. However, does this fade from colour to colour or just changes?

Comment: Managed to use my little knowledge of javascript and get it to fade. Thanks.

Comment: `i = i++;`? Lose the `i = ` part. How about replacing both lines with `i = ++i % colors.length;`?